# where to find the format borders and shading dialog box word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word

I'm trying to create a document in word 2007 and I can't seem to delete that solid black line that extended from margin to margin. I've found in the internet that, you can go to format borders but this is only available in 2003. 
Does anybody know in 2007?

Thanks

ps. OS: Win 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Word 2007 : Borders and Shading Options](http://www.uwec.edu/help/Word07/bordshad.htm) :

> From the Ribbon, select the Home
>   command tab. Within the Paragraph
>   section, the Shading and Border
>   options are available.
>
> [image]

(Unrelated note: If you are having adaptation problems to the Ribbon, see [Classic Menu for Office 2007](http://download.cnet.com/Classic-Menu-for-Office-2007/3000-18483_4-10637184.html).)

If your problem is the magic dark-line that Word generates via the feature of "AutoFormat as you type" (same thing that capitalizes new sentences), and if it is too late to hit Ctrl-Z to undo, then you must apply `Format =>  Borders and Shading => None`, but to the paragraph **before** the line. Ensure that it says this change is being applied to the paragraph.

Comment: thanks for this, but I can't find a way on how to get rid this dark line, it looks like an underline but it isn't. Because I tried to create an underline on the same text and the underline has a different spacing. This is just so strange...

Comment: I have added more info.

Comment: yes i think this is the magic dark line that word generates. I tried this then the line went above of the sentence. And it didn't go away

Comment: I also once had a very hard such case where nothing worked. I ended up copying the text before and after to a new document ...

Comment: yes that's what I just did now. I copied the text and start a new document. thanks for your help